# How can I know when the connection stream closed using Requests library?

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, stream

I'm connecting to an API stream. This connection is always active and I receive data from this API. My problem is that sometimes the connection closes and I need to connect again, but my code does not open any exception for this closed connection. It is as if the connection was still active, but without receiving any data. How can I know when the connection drops?

My code:

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    response.raise_for_status()

    for line in response.iter_lines():
        if line:
            print(line)
        else:
          print("No data returned.")

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Error connection:", e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out via the API documentation that if I pass an extra parameter called 'Heartbeat' in the url, every 10 seconds a Heartbeat event is sent to test the connection. So I'm passing a timeout in the API call with a value of 20 seconds, if the connection drops, after 20 seconds I have an exception in which I use it to try to reconnect.

```
http = requests.Session()

while True:
    try:
        resp = http.get(url, stream=True, timeout=20)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            # Do things

     except Exception as error:
        logging.info(f'Error: {error}')
```